# Referencing within an align

Tags: align

The following LaTeX document:

```
\begin{align*}
    p{(A,RM,OL,O,LC)}   &=p(A)\;p(RM\mid A)\;p(OL\mid A,RM)\;p(O \mid A, RM, OL)    \\ & 
    \; \; \; \;p(LC\mid A, RM, OL,O) \label{eq:JPExample}
\end{align*}
```

does not display the reference `\ref{eq:JPExample}`. Why?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`.

Comment: You are trying to refer to an equation that has no number. It makes no sense. Change `align*` to `align` then it works.

Comment: ok. :) i am pretty new in latex :P but thanks for editing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your alignment is not good. Here is how I would do it:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  p(A,RM,OL,O,LC)
  ={}& p(A) \cdot p(RM \mid A) \cdot p(OL \mid A,RM) \nonumber\\
     &  \cdot p(O \mid A,RM,OL) \cdot p(LC \mid A,RM,OL,O). \label{eq:JPExample}
\end{align}
Here is equation~\eqref{eq:JPExample}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output1]

or

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
  p(A,RM,OL,O,LC)
  ={}& p(A) \cdot p(RM \mid A) \cdot p(OL \mid A,RM) \\
     &  \cdot p(O \mid A,RM,OL) \cdot p(LC \mid A,RM,OL,O). \label{eq:JPExample}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
Here is equation~\eqref{eq:JPExample}.

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Notice the difference in the tag placement between the two approaches.

Also, I've

- removed the redundant brackets in `p{(...)}`,
- put multiplications signs between each factor,
- moved one of the factor from the first line to the latter.

Comment: you don't need `gather`; in this context, `equation` would be better.  (`aligned` would also work as an alternative to `split`.)

Answer (score 4):

You can only reference equations which also have a number.
Since you are using the `align*` environment, your equation does not have a number and hence cannot be referenced. In the `align` environment (without the `*`) they get a number and can be referenced.

Since you have multiple lines and probably only want one of these lines to have a number and to be referenced, you can use the `\nonumber` command from the [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) package to prevent those lines from getting a number.

In the example below, the first equation is assigned numbering "(1)" and can be referenced. The second equation is not assigned any number and cannot be referenced.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}  %align environment and equations withount unmbering

\begin{document}
  \begin{align}
    E & = m \cdot c^2
    \label{eq:einstein}
    \\
    c^2 & = a^2 + b^2 
    \nonumber    
  \end{align}
  This is a reference to equation \eqref{eq:einstein}.
 %This is a reference to equation (1).
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE example for equations with/without reference]

Note: The `\eqref{...}` command produces references enclosed in brackets as "equation (1)" compared to "equation 1" using the `\ref{...}` command.